# Substring for specific characters

Tags: java

I have a file name as a String from which I want to extract the account number. The String will look like the below..

jack-16-05-2014-13-32-48_216043_PHOTO.jpg

The account number will always be before the word "PHOTO" and it will always be either 5 or 6 characters length. In this example it is "216043"

The total String length can vary because the name at the beginning can be different.

Can someone please share what is the best way in Java to extract the account number.

Thanks.

Comment: No, because Stack Overflow doesn't exist to give you an answer without you doing any work (but people will do it anyways)

Comment: Take a look at the String API. There are several methods there that you can use. Maybe lastIndexOf(...), substring(...). Maybe split(...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jack-16-05-2014-13-32-48_216043_PHOTO.jpg
                         ^    ^
                       Start End
```

Try This.

```
 String s="jack-16-05-2014-13-32-48_216043_PHOTO.jpg";
 System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf("_")+1,s.lastIndexOf("_")));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
216043
```

NOTE: As it will only get Number beetween *_TwoUnderscores_* and will work only for this case it will not be useful if your string has underscore other than this places.